# Nested query using alias with google sheets QUERY()

Tags: sql, google-sheets

How would you translate this query using google sheets =QUERY() function?

```
SELECT 
    u1.*
FROM
    user_details u1
WHERE
    u1.login_time = (SELECT 
            MAX(u2.login_time)
        FROM
            user_details u2
        WHERE
            u2.user_name = u1.user_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps? This assumes that A2:A has the Login Time and B1 is equal to the client name

More details would be useful - what is the goal of the function? Should it return a single row or an array?

```
=QUERY({user_details}, "SELECT * FROM WHERE Col1 = '"&MAX(A2:A)&"' AND Col2 = '"&B1&"'",0)
```